# How to force stop a service in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services

I'm trying to disable the beep service on my Windows 7 laptop.

I've tried to use "net stop beep", but that just results in "Service could not be stopped".

I've also tried stopping the service via the device manager / Non-Plug-N-Play Service, but it gets stuck in the "Stopping" phase, and continues to beep.

I'm the admin of this computer, so presumably I can give myself any required access rights required.

Comment: [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/turn-off-the-annoying-windows-xp-system-beeps/) is for XP, but did you try the regedit method? Same key exists in W7

Comment: I'm assuming the Beep service is somewhat special. I can't stop mine either, but other services can be stopped just fine.

Comment: Raystation, that did it! Add post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You mean the «beep» *driver* I supposed...

If so use MS TechNet Sysinternals **Autoruns**.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902

Set the *options* -> filter options: uncheck "hide windows entries"

In the *tab* "drivers" uncheck (but NOT delete!) this:

Beep    BEEP Driver Microsoft Corporation   c:\windows\system32\drivers\beep.sys

Restart Windows.

Hope this help. Let us know.  :)

Comment: @samj also you can disable it via the device manager, just "view" "show hidden devices" in non-plug&play, double click on it, in the "drivers" tab , disable and reboot.  I dont know of the ramifications of shutting that off yet.  The "beep driver" is not completly related to the default beep, as shown at how-to. defaults will go to to the motherbaord speaker to beep, but only when there is no normal sound card & sound driver working.